LED TE and TM polarization
I’m having some difficulty understanding the concept of polarization in UV LEDs. To summarize the literature, for UV LEDs emitting at longer wavelengths the light they emit is mostly TE polarized, that is, the e-field vector is perpendicular to the c-axis (equivalently, perpendicular to the quantum well growth direction/the light’s plane of incidence, p.o.i.). Therefore, the photons are mostly emitted through the substrate or surface, and can easily be utilized. The b-field is parallel to the c-axis in this situation.
On the other hand, at shorter wavelengths the emission is mostly TM polarized, that is, the e-field vector is parallel to the c-axis/growth direction/p.o.i. (the b-field is perpendicular), and therefore photons are mostly emitted parallel to the c-plane/surface, making them hard to extract.
I understand how/why light is easier/harder to extract when emitted through the LED surface/parallel to it, but I’m trying to visualize why it follows that if the e/b fields point in a certain direction that it necessarily follows that the light should propagate in a particular direction.
Attached is a diagram I drew showing the device surface, p.o.i., etc. Using the right hand rule for an electromagnetic wave (e-field represented by the thumb, b-field by the index finger, direction of propagation, $\overrightarrow{v}$, by the middle finger), I seem to be able to get $\overrightarrow{v}$ to point either perpendicular to, or parallel to, the device’s surface regardless of the choice of TE or TM polarization, depending on how I choose to point my other fingers, which I find confusing.

For example, lets say the light is TE polarized. I start by pointing my thumb “out of the page” to represent $\overrightarrow{e}$ being perpendicular to the p.o.i. Next, I point my index finger to the right, to represent $\overrightarrow{b}$ being parallel to the p.o.i. This leaves my middle finger ($\overrightarrow{v}$) pointing “up”, out of the surface. So, TE polarisation gives me light escaping the surface, as expected.
However, lets say I point my thumb ($\overrightarrow{e}$) “out of the page again”. Now I point my index finger “upwards” out of the device surface (I assume this still counts as $\overrightarrow{b}$ being parallel to the p.o.i.). Now my middle finger ($\overrightarrow{v}$) is pointing to the left, i.e. parallel to the surface.
Likewise I can get TM polarization to give me v pointing out of the surface (thumb pointing right, index finger pointing into the page, middle finger pointing up)  or parallel to it, (thumb pointing up, index finger into the page, middle finger pointing left).
This leaves me confused as to how TE polarization yields light that is preferentially emitted out of the surface, and TM preferentially parallel to the surface, in UV LEDs. I feel like I’m misunderstanding the application of the right hand rule, but any advice would be welcome.

You have the right idea. The E and B vectors are perpendicular to each other. They define a plane. Light travels perpendicular to that plane.
For TE polarization, E is perpendicular to the c axis and therefore parallel to the surface. But you don't know the angle of the M vector. If it happens to be parallel to the surface, light travels in the direction of the c axis. If it happens to be perpendicular to the surface light travels parallel to the surface. It might be at an angle to the surface. So light can be easy or difficult to extract, but it is easy for at least some cases.
For TM polarization, E is parallel to the c axis. The means the M is parallel to the surface. And light always travels parallel to the surface. Always difficult to extract.

Thank you for the clear explanation. I think my confusion was in thinking that e.g. for TM polarization the E vector could lie at any angle w.r.t. to the surface normal, as long as it lay within the plane of incidence. In that situation it could point "left" or "right". However, from your description I understand E must be parallel to the c-axis and thus always point "up" or "down".
If the E vector is strictly perpendicular or parallel to the c-axis as you indicated, I can see that light will tend to be easier or hard, respectively, to extract.
